# How to remove black artifacts on map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

How can I remove the black pixels on the shapefile below?

I have never seen this before after receiving a shapefile and categorizing it. This shapefile shows percentage of flooded area per municipality. I'm displaying polygons here (municipalities) but I can't get rid of the black pixels. Are they no data values?

[image: black artifacts on map]

Comment: I can't follow the logic why this is closed, can someone explain why this is off-topic? @underdark

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn I chose "cannot be reproduced" since the the issue has nothing to do with no value pixels. I don't think the question has future value as it stands. Feel free to reopen if you think otherwise.

Comment: I think that's lack of knowledge about taxonomy while the issue itself is something others have run into as well. I'll reopen with the term "artifacts" instead of "no value".

Comment: My first thought was also that what's showing is an artifact (i.e. a black symbol outline).  On-topic and reproducible.

Answer (score 5):

The symbol most likely has a black outline. Go to the style configuration of the layer and set the stroke color to Transparent.

*No data value* is a term normally used with respect to raster data, while with vector data (like shapefiles) normally the term to use is *NULL value* for an attribute, but that's not related to anything that's going on here.

Comment: that's exactly it! I feel embarrased.... Thank you very much Matthias!